# Angular - unit test spy are not recognising that the function has been called

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, karma-jasmine, angular-directive

I've got a test component that I use for testing directives:

```
export class UnitTestComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(BackgroundLoadedDirective) backgroundLoaded: BackgroundLoadedDirective;

  public url = 'https://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/flip.jpg';

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  loaded(): void {
    console.log(true)
  }
}
```

Then I have this directive which I would like to write some tests for:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[backgroundLoaded]'
})

export class BackgroundLoadedDirective {
  @Input('backgroundLoaded') set url(value) {
    this.createImage(value);
  };

  get url() {
    return this._url;
  }

  @Output() loaded: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  public img: HTMLImageElement;

  private _url: string;

  @HostBinding('class.background-loaded')
  isLoaded = false;

  createImage(url: string): void {

    // This gets logged as expected
    console.log(url);

    this._url = url;

    this.img = new Image();

    this.img.onload = () => {
      this.isLoaded = true;
      this.load.emit(url);
    };

    this.img.src = url;
  }
}
```

Then I have just this test so far:

```
describe('BackgroundLoadedDirective', () => {

  let component: UnitTestComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<UnitTestComponent>;
  let spy: any;

  beforeEach(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        UnitTestComponent,
        BackgroundLoadedDirective
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [
        {provide: ComponentFixtureAutoDetect, useValue: true}
      ]
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UnitTestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should create a fake img tag', () => {

    spy = spyOn(component.backgroundLoaded, 'createImage').and.callThrough();

    expect(component.backgroundLoaded.img).toBeTruthy();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

The problem is that the test fails saying:

```
Expected spy createImage to have been called.
```

Why isn't the spy working despite the function being called?

**EDIT:**

Just to clarify, this is the test component's html which applies the directive and gives it the url.

```
<div [urlToBackground]="url" [backgroundLoaded]="url" (loaded)="loaded($event)"></div>
```

Comment: Maybe i'm blind, but i don't see where you call this function.

Comment: Were you expecting that `.and.callThrough();` would call the function?

Comment: i think he sets the url in his testComponents template which would call it because of his setter function. Could you confirm this?

Comment: @lexith That is correct. I'll add it for clarification.

Comment: @FrankModica The function is called whenever the setter is called. So it's called the first time that the image url is evaluated by the directive.

Comment: @FrankModica I'm creating a spy by accessing the directive instance first using `component.backgroundLoaded`, which is the `@ViewChild` of the test component. Then I'm creating a spy on the `createImage` function. I'm not sure spying on the setter itself would make any difference since that just calls the `createImage` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically what's interfering are angulars lifecycle hooks. Your test just doesn't cares enough in terms of timing.

To make it easier to test, trigger a change and then test if your setter works (and calls the function you're spying on).

Something like this:

```
it('should create a fake img tag', () => {
    let spy: jasmine.Spy = spyOn(component.backgroundLoaded, 'createImage').and.callThrough();

    comp.backgroundLoaded.url = 'foobar';
    fixture.detectChanges(); // wait for the change detection to kick in

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Hope it helps.

(edit: removed one `detectChanges()` for `ngOnInit`, because it's not needed here and should be called before the test anyway)

Comment: It did not work for me because i forgot `.and.callThrough();`! :D